# Streamline question

Tags: calculus

Let $\textbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a vector field defined as
\begin{equation}
\textbf{F}(x,y) = (x^2, y+1)
\end{equation}
Find the streamline of $\textbf{F}$ that passes through the point $(1,1)$.

**Answer**

Define 
\begin{equation}
\textbf{r}(t) = (x(t), y(t))
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\textbf{r}'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t)) = \textbf{F}(x(t),y(t)) = (x^2(t), y(t)+1)
\end{equation}
so we get two differential equations. Namely
\begin{equation}
x'(t) = x^2(t) \mbox{ and } y'(t) = y(t) + 1
\end{equation}
We beging solving
\begin{align}
y(t) = e^{t} \int e^{-t} dy = e^{t} (-e^{-t} + C) = e^{t}C - 1
\end{align}
and
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}}{x^2(t)} = \int 1 \partial t
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
x(t)= -\frac{1}{t + B}
\end{equation}
Now 
\begin{equation}
\textbf{r}(0) = (x(0), y(0)) = (-\frac{1}{t + B}, e^{t}C - 1) = (1,1)
\end{equation}
So $C = 2$ and $B = -1$ and
\begin{equation}
\textbf{r}(t) = (x(t), y(t)) = (-\frac{1}{t - 1}, 2e^{t} - 1)
\end{equation}

Is this correct?

Comment: In the last step, when $t=0$, you should have $({-1\over 0+B}, e^0C-1)=(1,1)$. So $C=2, B=-1$ and $r(t)=({-1\over t-1}, 2e^t-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine except for the last step where you're solving for the constants.
When $t=0$, you should have 
$${\bf r}(0)=\bigl(\,\textstyle{−1\over 0+B},e^0\cdot C−1\,\bigr)=(1,1)\ \ \Rightarrow \ \  B=−1,\ C=2 
\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ {\bf r}(t)=\bigl(\,{-1\over t-1},2e^t−1\,\bigr). $$

And on a picky note, at the outset, you should define ${\bf r}(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$, ${\bf r}(0)=(1,1)$.